# Improving UI performance

Tags: android, performance, android-profiler

I checked my UI with Android studio profiler (Recorded system trace) and I got following result:
[image]
As you can see here it takes 28ms for a frame to load when I open my fragment.
Also we can see that almost all time is taken by traversal and measure. I tried to refactor my xml and now it looks like:

```
<MotionLayout>
    <SwiperefreshLayout>
        <NestedScrollView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <include
                 layout="cardView1">
                <include
                 layout="cardView2">
                //..........
                <include
                 layout="cardVie7">
            <LinearLayout>
        <NestedScrollView>
    <SwipeRefreshLayout>
<MotionLayout>
```

It's just complex UI with lots of nested cards which can have recycleview ot other content inside. After my refactoring there still some problems with the frame time as you can see. Is there a way improve my UI performance or maybe at least get more detailed info of what's wrong and why it takes so long to draw the UI?

Comment: I think we need to see your MotionScene as that can have rather complex effects.

Comment: Also if you have a MotionLayout - why not implement the swipe to refresh inside that rather than using the `SwipeToRefreshLayout` in between that and your content? Probably wasting some measure cycles on that.

Comment: I've tried to remove motion scene but it didn't improve the performance. I use SwipeToRefreshLayout b/c it's industry standard and it fully satisfies our requirements. I agree it may worth to try implementing it with motionlayout to see the difference. But right now I improved the performance and described it in my answer so frame drop not even noticeable now when you pullttorefresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding custom Trace events and profiling the app I found that the recyclerView items inflation takes almost all of the frame time. The problem was solved with using [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) and [RecyclerView Async Loading](https://proandroiddev.com/improve-ui-performance-async-recyclerview-layout-loading-7eb525ab19d0)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MotionLayout looks unnecessary. Also, you may use the RecyclerView to show Cards.

Comment: Motionlayout is being used for animation. I skipped that in my example for simplicity.  I tried to disable animation but it doesn't affect performance.

Comment: I didn't use Recyclerview because those cards are really different from each other. One can have a chart, another can have another Recyclerview etc. Didn't want to have too many complex view holders

Comment: Also I need to always keep all the cards on a screen so there is no necessity in recyclerview.

Comment: layout has too many complex views. I suggest that you may try viewStub + asyncLayoutInflater to lazyloading. This way will improve initial layout performance.

Comment: Sounds like a solution. I'll try, thanks!